# how to automatically disable a button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to automatically disable a button for a period of time in vb.net?
my project is voting management using vb.net and Sql server .my voting starts only from 9 am-10 am .so the button which i log in should automatically disable before and after the given time.

Comment: check the time at Page Load and disable the button if necessary.

Comment: no it should automatically disable after the given time

Comment: Are you working for the company that did the u.s. elections? But seriously, is this a web or desktop application?

Comment: and im doing it for my college project desktop application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form/page loading, use DateTime to get the current hour:

```
Dim currentDate As System.DateTime
Dim currentHour As Integer

currentDate = Date.Now()
currentHour = currentDate.Hour

If currentHour = 9 Or currentHour = 10 Then
   button.Visible = False
Endif
```

Comment: the button must be automatically set to enable or disable based on the timing. can u help with that?

Comment: You mean that the user don't have to refresh your form to get the new state of your button ?

Comment: the user cannot use the button before or after the specified timing even if he refreshes\

Comment: I did got that, but does he need to refresh to see the new state of the button once it's visible/invisible?

Comment: Contact me with mp or create a new topic for that ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200704/how-to-automatically-include-characters-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 2):

Run a `Thread` on start-up which from this point on should loop forever. Check the `DateTime.Now` to check what time it is currently. `Enable` and `Disable` it if the time is between your allotted times. Then calculate how long you need to wait before the end of the window, put the `thread` to `sleep` for that amount of time.

**Edit**: example code

Make sure you include this at the top. `Imports System.Threading`

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim myThread As System.Threading.Thread
    myThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadLoop)
    myThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ThreadLoop()
    While True
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            Sub() myButton.IsEnabled = (DateTime.Now.Hour = 9))
        Thread.Sleep(10000) ' This implementation just rechecks every 10 seconds
    End While
End Sub
```

**Note**: This solution automatically updates the UI when the time changes.

Comment: can i get coding for my time (9am-10am)\